# Dropping Database in Powershell with Invoke-Sqlcmd tells me DB is in use even though it's not

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am trying to drop a database like this

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database Dbname-ServerInstance ".\SQLEXPRESS" -Query "drop database DbName;"
```

in a powershell script and I get this message:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot drop database "DbName" because it is currently in use.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database Dbname-ServerInstance ".\SQLEXPRESS" -Que ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

The Database is not in use. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The database *is* in use -- you're connected to it! Try `-Database master`.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is in use -- you're connected to it! Try -Database master. – Jeroen Mostert